# The equivalence definitions of convergence in distribution

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

There is a statement about the equivalence properties of weak convergence in wikipedia:

> In the case $S$ ≡ $\mathbf{R}$ with its usual topology, if $F_n$ and
> $F$ denote the cumulative distribution functions of the measures $P_n$
> and $P$, respectively, then $P_n$ converges weakly to $P$ if and only
> if $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} F_n(x) = F(x)$ for all points $x \in
> > \mathbf{R}$ at which $F$ is continuous.

I think the statement holds due to one of the equivalence conditions in Protmanteau Theorem: Let $(P_n)$ and $P$ be probability measures on $\mathbf{R}^{d}$. $(P_n)$ converges weakly to $P$ if and only if for any Borel set $ B \subseteq \mathbf{R}^{d}$, if $P(\partial B) = 0$, then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P_n(B) = P(B).$

I'm thinking to let $d = 1$, take the probability measure $P$ as the law (or distribution) of $X$, and since the endpoints of any intervals are of measure 0, then the above statement is proved. However, I don't know whether this thought is correct and have a trouble to write them down with logical math statements. I have found a few similar questions but the target are not relevant to this proof.

Can anyone give me some guidances? Thanks!

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures

Comment: You can find a proof here: https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf

Comment: Can I also conclude this statement by using Pólya’s theorem?

Comment: I don't know what Polyas theorem is. But this equivalence is straightforward by approximating a bounded continuous function by step functions, and by approximating an indicator of an interval by a bou ded continuous function.

Comment: @Mason Thanks, I think you're talking about necessity. May I ask how to construct such a simple function? Is it empirical CDF?

Comment: Look at theorem 3.2.9 on page 119.

Comment: Okay, I get it. But this part of the proof is only for sufficiency. Would you explain the other part?

Comment: The theorem proves equivalence. One direction uses Skorohod representation, while the other direction uses a direct construction.